# How to subtract char out from string in c++?

Tags: c++, string, subtraction

Hello I want to know how to subract string from string

For example

If string s = "124ab"
I can easily extract integer by using sstream but I don't know how to extract string

I want to extract ab from s;
I have tons of string and they don't have any rule.
s can be "3456fdhgab" or "34a678"

Comment: Do you want `34a678` to become `34` or `34678`?

Comment: What do you mean by `string(char)`?

Comment: @Aziz I just want to let you know it can be single char like 'a' or string like "ab". Sorry for confusing. I want to extract string you can just disregard expression string(char). it just meant string.

Comment: As numbers are also valid as that what you expect `string` is, you can't do it with the given overloads of istream. Use regex for example. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex

Comment: @Klaus Sorry for confusing I will modify it.

Comment: I am not confused. :-) You want to pick the character range from a..z and numerals as numbers. That, as said, can't be done with the overloads for istream::operator>> so you have to use regex or any other kind of selection of characters as you want

Comment: @Klaus I'm sorry but,I don't get it well. I don't need numerals. I just need to extract a to z  from string.

Comment: So simply do it... :-) You may want to use regex... again :-) or you simply loop over the content and pick the chars as they are in the range... A simple loop with comparison seems to simple enough to do it yourself I expect. To go with regex simply read the docs already linked in my comment above! Or you can go with any kind of filters or .... there are so many options... handcrafted or by using stl stuff.

Comment: The desired behavior is unclear as asked. For example, do you want to remove a specific string (e.g. "3456fdhgab" to "3456fdhg")? Do you want the string with letters removed (e.g. "3456fdhgab" to "3456", and "34a678" to "34678")? Do you want the letters from the string (e.g. "3456fdhgab" to "fdhgab")? Something else? Please show desired results in the question. You should also check that the question doesn't already exist on SO and close this one if it does.

Comment: @outis Thanks for detailed comments! But i think i just found answer, so I answer myself. Thanks. But still I will modify my question.

Comment: Great you found an answer. A major goal of SO is to be a repository of programming Q&As. Clarifying your question will help in this goal, as will checking for duplicates. The [help] has more about what SO is all about.

Comment: Looks to be a duplicate of "[How can I concisely find all digits in a string without using a loop?](//stackoverflow.com/q/27536860/90527)" (and possibly others).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`std::isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) to check if a character is a digit. You can use the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) to remove characters that are digits.

Because `std::isdigit` has an overload it has to be wrapped in a lambda to be used in the algorithm:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

int main() {
    std::string inp{"124ab"};
    inp.erase(std::remove_if(inp.begin(),inp.end(),[](char c){return std::isdigit(c);}),inp.end());
    std::cout << inp;
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/hW4YTrbWK):

```
ab
```

---

And because you asked for using a stringstream, here is how you can extract non-digits with a custom `operator<<`:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <sstream>

struct only_non_digits {
    std::string& data;    
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const only_non_digits& x) {
    for (const auto& c : x.data){
        if (std::isdigit(c)) continue;
        os << c;
    }
    return os;
}    

int main() {
    std::string inp{"124ab"};
    std::cout << only_non_digits{inp} << "\n";
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << only_non_digits{inp};
    std::cout << ss.str() << "\n";
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/3EznxnGzG):

```
ab
ab
```

Answer (score -2):

```
string removeNumbers(string str)
{
    int current = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        if (!isdigit(str[i])) {
            str[current] = str[i];
            current++;
        }
    }
    return str.substr(0, current);
}

int main()
{
     string str;
     cout <<"Enter the string : " <<endl;
     getline(cin,str);
     cout <<"Modified string : " <<removeNumbers(str) <<endl;

}
```

Comment: @Klaus the code is reusing the argument (which is passed by value). The substring is guaranteed to be shorter than the full string, so the code is ok

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Ubs! Yes, you are right!

Comment: Since major goal of SO is to be a repository of programming Q&As, providing [additional context](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/90527) regarding why & how this answer works and when it should be used will improve its long-term value by helping other readers.

Comment: @outis OK! I will :)